# clearTimeout in Redux action file

Tags: redux, global-variables, settimeout, redux-thunk, cleartimeout

I'm trying to implement auto-refresh (fetch data from API again) functionality in redux app. I was wandering if it is ok to use global variable in `../action.js` to use clearTimeout in other function - for stop auto-refresh after changing page or fulfill any other condition.
Is it ok or should I take different approach?

**../action.js**

```
import fetchWeather from '../../shared/fetchWeather';
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

let refreshTimeout = null;


export const refresh = (endpoint, queryParams) => {
  return dispatch => {
    refreshTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(initWeather(endpoint, queryParams));
    }, 1000)  
  }
}

export const initWeather = (endpoint, queryParams) => {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchWeather(endpoint, queryParams)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setWeather(response.data));
        dispatch(refresh(endpoint, queryParams))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchWeatherFailed(error.message))
      })
  }
}

export const initForecast = (endpoint, queryParams) => {
  clearTimeout(refreshTimeout); // clearTimeout to stop refreshing (re-fetching data)
  return dispatch => {
    fetchWeather(endpoint, queryParams)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setForecast(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchForecastFailed(error.message))
      })
  }
}
```

.
.
.